# Android Accessibility service interact with numerous switches at once

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I was wondering if there is a good way to turn on/off numerous switches at once using Accessibility service.

So basically I have a view that contains a RecyclerView that has about 40 switches in it and I need a way to switch them on/off as fast as possible. Here is what I tried.

```
public static void scrollView(final AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {

    if (nodeInfo == null) return;

    if (nodeInfo.isScrollable()) {
        if (nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD)) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    turnOffSwitches(nodeInfo);
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    }
}

public static void turnOffSwitches(final AccessibilityNodeInfo parentView) {
    if (parentView.getClassName().equals("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final AccessibilityNodeInfo child = parentView.getChild(i);
            final Boolean isLasteOne = (i == parentView.getChildCount() - 1);
            child.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
            if (isLasteOne) {
                scrollView(parentView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried introducing a delay between ACTION_CLICK actions that helped a bit but did not solve my problem fully. So the issue that I am having is that not all switches get turned off. It seems like there is a limit on how fast this can be done. So my question is, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD - it's not paging just scrolling some portion of your whole matrix of elements and some visible are already switched to the state so in your next loop you are trying to click on those which were already swiched (next visible area overlaps with previous one)

1. either check the state on/off - if the view is not already at the desired state before changing it
2. or check event.getScrollX() and event.getScrollY() if action was not already performed in those bounds